# Find Indexes of Non-NaN Values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large dataset (roughly 200000x400), however I have it filtered and only a few hundred values remain, the rest are NaN. I would like to create a list of indexes of those remaining values. I can't seem to find a simple enough solution.

```
    0     1     2
0   NaN   NaN   1.2
1   NaN   NaN   NaN   
2   NaN   1.1   NaN   
3   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   1.4   NaN   1.01
```

For instance, I would like a list of [(0,2), (2,1), (4,0), (4,2)].

Comment: Please choose [Nickil Maveli's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41150427/5741205) as a correct one - it's much faster and more idiomatic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the dataframe to it's equivalent `NumPy` array representation and check for `NaNs` present. Later, take the negation of it's corresponding indices (indicating non nulls) using [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html). Since the output required must be a list of tuples, you could then make use of generator `map` function applying `tuple` as function to every iterable of the resulting array.

```
>>> list(map(tuple, np.argwhere(~np.isnan(df.values))))
[(0, 2), (2, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your column names are of `int` dtype:

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]:
     0    1     2
0  NaN  NaN  1.20
1  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  NaN  1.1   NaN
3  NaN  NaN   NaN
4  1.4  NaN  1.01

In [74]: df.columns.dtype
Out[74]: dtype('int64')

In [75]: df.stack().reset_index().drop(0, 1).apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
Out[75]: [(0, 2), (2, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2)]
```

if your column names are of `object` dtype:

```
In [81]: df.columns.dtype
Out[81]: dtype('O')

In [83]: df.stack().reset_index().astype(int).drop(0,1).apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
Out[83]: [(0, 2), (2, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2)]
```

Timing for 50K rows DF:

```
In [89]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [90]: df.shape
Out[90]: (50000, 3)

In [91]: %timeit list(map(tuple, np.argwhere(~np.isnan(df.values))))
10 loops, best of 3: 144 ms per loop

In [92]: %timeit df.stack().reset_index().drop(0, 1).apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.67 s per loop
```

**Conclusion:** the [Nickil Maveli's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150427/5741205) is 12 times faster for this test DF