# Find Indexes of a List of DataFrame that have NaN Values - Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a list of Data Frames in which some Data Frames have `NaN` values. So far I can identify `NaN` values for a single Data Frame using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226083/how-to-find-which-columns-contain-any-nan-value-in-pandas-dataframe-python).

How can I find the index of the list where a Data Frame has `NaN` values.

Sample list of `dffs`,

```
[                   
 var1       var1  
14.171250  13.593813
13.578317  13.595329
10.301850  13.580139
9.930217   NaN
6.192517   13.561943
NaN        13.565149
6.197983   13.572509,  

  var1       var2    
2.456183  5.907528
5.052017  5.955731
5.960000  5.972480
8.039317  5.984608
7.559217  5.985348
6.933633  5.979438,

 var1       var1  
14.171250  23.593813
23.578317  23.595329
56.301850  23.580139
90.930217   22.365676
89.192517   33.561943
86.23654   53.565149
NaN        13.572509,  
...]
```

I need to get the results in a list `indexes` `0` and `2` that have `NaN` values.

So far I tried this,

```
df_with_nan = []
for df in dffs:
    df_with_nan.append(df.columns[df.isnull().any()])
```

Per above `for` loop I get column names, `var1` and `var2`. However, I need the indexes of those Data Frames when i loop through it. Any help or suggestion would be great.

Comment: When you say indices... you mean the indices of the list?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, index of the list. So, I can identify data frames in that index.

Comment: You're almost there... try `if df.isnull().any().max():` Use enumerate, append the df index in the if block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Indexes of Non-NaN Values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150238/find-indexes-of-non-nan-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there... just use `enumerate` to loop with indices, and `df.isnull().values.any()` (faster than `df.isnull().any().max()`) to test:

```
df_with_nan = []
for i, df in enumerate(dffs):
    if df.isnull().values.any():
        df_with_nan.append(i)
```

Granted, a list comp is shorter, but go for whatever you prefer.

Comment: @COLDSPEED you have `max` here and @Alexander answer, `sum` is used, why did you use `max`? is it `max` index?

Comment: @i.n.n.m Sum is a fancy way of using or over booleans. Max of T and F is the same as max of 1 and 0. I'd wager this is faster than sum though. You should do a benchmark before accepting an answer ;)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you. yes, i am trying to find specifics on why they were different :)

Comment: `any().any()` would be faster still as it stops executing after the the first null value.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, any().any() came to mind first before any().max(), but it looks ugly :( Anyway, I'll let you have it, :)

Comment: @Alexander What do you think of `df.isnull().values.any()`?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be much faster.

Comment: @i.n.n.m I have a faster version for you. Look at my edit.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, yes, this is much faster, thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional list comprehension to enumerate over all dataframes in your list and return the enumerated index value of those that contain any null values.

```
df_with_nan = [n for n, df in enumerate(dffs) if sum(df.isnull().any())]
```

Comment: thank you, list comprehension way works, if you could explain why you used `sum` here?

Comment: Using `sum` gives you the total number of columns that contain a `nan` value.  Anything greater than zero evaluates to `True`.  You could also use `df.isnull().any().any()`.